# Audio visualization in React Native with expo cli

Tags: react-native, audio, expo, visualization, react-native-cli

I'm looking for a way to visualize a recording on React Native with expo cli (not react native cli), but all the solutions are for react native cli's. Thanks

I tried to eject expo but later decided it's not what I wanted because I want to keep expo.